# How MVC4 uses bundling virtual path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

In the Microsoft MVC4, I see something called `bundling` for minifying and caching static resources such as `CSS` and `JavaScript`. In the `ScriptBundle` method I see the first parameter that called `virtual path` and it should be relative only.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));
```

For example, `~/bundles/jquery` in above code.

I have one question, how `bundling` uses this `virtual path`? Is this used for something like file caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javascript and CSS Minifying/Bundling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnwebdevs/archive/2012/01/20/javascript-and-css-minifying-bundling-with-the-microsoft-web-optimization-nuget-package.aspx)

> Now, the way the JS/CSS minifying works is that it will dynamically
>   inspect all your files, read them, minify them and then cache the
>   result to be served later. This allows us to modify our files and have
>   all the files re-minified. When one of our JS/CSS files get modified
>   again, this process will restart until either the cache expires or a
>   file change.

Also look at this post [ScriptBundle and StyleBundle names and
includes](http://forums.asp.net/post/5038229.aspx) and link in this post for more details.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. These links don't explain why I can't just say '
    new ScriptBundle("mountain").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.js")'

Answer (score 11):

"The new ScriptBundle object is given a virtual path which can be anything you like. It effectively acts as a name by which the bundle can be identified. It does not have to match an existing path in the web site folder structure."

Taken from http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/197/optimising-asp-net-web-pages-sites-bundling-and-minification

@Richard, in case you are still looking for the answer.

Comment: A very important point that is completely missing from the documentation and isn't obvious.